# td element is wider than its max-width property

Tags: css

I have this situation[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvIv1.png)

td element has property max-width: 80px, and it is not overridden by another style definition. But width of the element is 129.5px. How can it be??

Check it on http://gold.digitalit.co.il/product/aquarium/

Comment: `table`s and `flexbox`es will do that to you as they auto-adjust!

Comment: It is not exact duplicate, but the answer to both questions is the same